# Suppress Perforce Ant task output

Tags: ant, perforce

Is there a way to suppress the (many) output of a Perforce Ant task?
I've tried the globaloption but that seems to not work!

```
    <p4jsync files="//depot/${ProgramName}/@{Folder}@{Includes}" >
         <globaloption key="-q" value="true" />
         or 
         <globaloption key="q" value="true" />
    </p4jsync>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `ant-quiet` is one option.

http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Changing-the-verbosity-of-P4Ant-s-Output

Comment: Thanks! ant -quiet is to quit for me. I try to use the link.